# Trying to format a SQL Syntax for legacy code to include commas for format but return error

Tags: sql, function, reporting-services, formatting

When I run a custom function on this query to format this query to have commas. I am getting an error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '0.00000' to data type int.

Here is the query that works that is unmodified, it returns 2174... The outcome I truly desire is 2,174. Please proceed to the function below this one that shows where I add the function `dbo.fn_FormatWithCommas()`. It compiles, but that is when I get a returned error when I try to generate a report.

```
Convert(
        int,
        ROUND(
            Case
                When CONVERT(
                    VARCHAR(500),
                    DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE(@key, CY.PTIE_Local)
                ) = '' Then 0
                Else Convert(
                    numeric,
                    CONVERT(
                        VARCHAR(500),
                        DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE(@key, CY.PTIE_Local)
                    )
                ) * (
                    SELECT
                        ER.Exchange_Rate
                    FROM
                        Exchange_Rates ER
                    WHERE
                        ER.Currency_Code = ISNULL(
                            convert(
                                VARCHAR(500),
                                DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE(@key, CY.Local_Currency_Code)
                            ),
                            'USD'
                        )
                        AND ER.Year = dbo.getCurrentYear()
                )
            End,
            0
        )
    ) as 'CY PTIE (USD)',
```

Here is what I am trying to do. Notice that there is the added function `dbo.fn_FormatWithCommas()`

```
Convert(
    int,
    ROUND(
        Case
            When CONVERT(
                VARCHAR(500),
                DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE(@key, CY.PTIE_Local)
            ) = '' Then 0
            Else dbo.fn_FormatWithCommas(
                Convert(
                    numeric,
                    CONVERT(
                        VARCHAR(500),
                        DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE(@key, CY.PTIE_Local)
                    )
                ) * (
                    SELECT
                        ER.Exchange_Rate
                    FROM
                        Exchange_Rates ER
                    WHERE
                        ER.Currency_Code = ISNULL(
                            convert(
                                VARCHAR(500),
                                DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE(@key, CY.Local_Currency_Code)
                            ),
                            'USD'
                        )
                        AND ER.Year = dbo.getCurrentYear()
                )
            )
        End,
        0
    )
) as 'CY PTIE (USD)',
```

Please alter the code and show/tell me why I am getting it wrong. I am having problems decyphering between all the functions. I added a prettier format. hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry, there is no C#, but usualy C# devs know SQL. It's very common. Sorry.

Comment: @AluanHaddad done. Thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it by wrapping the entire script in a FORMAT(VALUE, 'N0')

```
FORMAT(Convert(int, ROUND(Case When CONVERT(VARCHAR(500),DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE(@key,CY.PTIE_Local)) = '' Then 0 
Else Convert(numeric, CONVERT(VARCHAR(500),DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE(@key,CY.PTIE_Local)))* 
(SELECT ER.Exchange_Rate FROM Exchange_Rates ER WHERE ER.Currency_Code = 
ISNULL(convert(VARCHAR(500),DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE(@key,CY.Local_Currency_Code)), 'USD')
AND ER.Year = dbo.getCurrentYear())  End, 0)), 'N0')  as 'CY PTIE (USD)',
```

Comment: Typically, I would avoid doing any formatting on values in the database or even in value expressions. Just return the raw number and set the `Format` property of the textbox to "n0". It will perform better and if you export to excel, the correct values will be exported, rather than the truncated formatted text versions.